# Setting the previous month as a default value in 'mmm' format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to create a temporary table where the period is always the previous month in abbreviation. For example today the default value would be 'Sep'.

I have this code but it throws me errors after trying add other values to the table:

```
create table tmp_hfm 
( 
    Entity_Code nvarchar(15),
    HFM_Account nvarchar(15),
    HFM_Segment nvarchar(15),
    Period date default format(month(getdate()) - 1, 'mmmm')
)
```

The error I get:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can someone advise on this please?

Comment: that not solved the problem

Comment: How about January?

Comment: `month()` returns `int` then you convert it to some string and then attempt to convert the resulting string to date.  If the string is "Sep" - how do you convert it to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to do.  You have defined `Period` as a `date` column.  `FORMAT()` returns a string.  They are not compatible.

Perhaps you want `period` to be `char(3)`, with a default of `format(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()), 'MMM')`.

For "Sep", I would be inclined to use `left(datename(month, dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), 3)`, unless you have a reason for preferring the internationalization functionality of `format()`.

Comment: if i use char(3) for this, I will have the default value of 'MMM' in every row. I need to have 'Sep'.(The previous month, in every month)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_hfm (
  Entity_Code NVARCHAR(15),
  HFM_Account NVARCHAR(15),
  HFM_Segment NVARCHAR(15),
  Period CHAR(3) DEFAULT FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 'MMM')
);
```

If you need to specify culture, you can add another parameter after 'MMM':

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_hfm (
  Entity_Code NVARCHAR(15),
  HFM_Account NVARCHAR(15),
  HFM_Segment NVARCHAR(15),
  Period CHAR(3) DEFAULT FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 'MMM', 'en-us')
);
```

Here is an SQL Fiddle for you: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63f6a/1)

Comment: I chose CHAR(3) for the Period column, because FORMAT 'MMM' always return 3 letters (at least for the cultures that I used till now). You can use whatever string datatype as you prefer.